# Определения, тесно связанные по смыслу с определяемым словом

Tags: пунктуация

В этом [учебнике](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_174) читаю такое правило:

> Определения, стоящие после определяемого слова, но тесно связанные по смыслу с ним или с другими членами предложения, не обособляются. В
> таких случаях, если изъять определение из состава предложения, фраза
> теряет смысл.
>
> Например:
>
> *Он мог услышать вещи для себя довольно неприятные* (Лермонтов).
>
> *Море у его ног лежало безмолвное и белое* (Паустовский).

Потом делаю упражнения и совершаю ошибки.

> 12. Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной, *равной пяти сантиметрам*.

Но ведь если удалить определение *равной пяти сантиметрам*, предложение не имеет смысла: *Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной*.

> 28. Страннее всего происшествия, *случающиеся на Невском проспекте*! (Гоголь).

Здесь я также не поставил запятую, по той же причине. Если удалить определение -- смысл теряется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This guide mixes two different cases, and does not explain them very well either.

---

> Он мог услышать вещи для себя довольно неприятные (Лермонтов).

There is no comma here not because the modifier is tightly linked to a subject (as the guide suggests), but for two reasons which must play together:

1. The extended modifier (*распространённое определение*) as a whole is a comment (*рема*) and as such has to be put towards the end of the sentence, which is not how Russian concording modifiers (*согласованные определения*) normally behave.
2. The modifier itself (adjective or participle) is the last word within the clause, so that all other words, dependent on it, should precede it.

The reason 2 was what the guide was really about.

The main idea is that sentence, as it goes, keeps putting the words so that the topic does not have to be separated using intonation, hence no need for isolating it with a comma.

Let's have a closer look.

The author has put the sentence in this order because *неприятные* is the ultimate comment of the sentence, and he wanted to put it into the very end to give it the right intonation. To do that, he has to violate normal Russian word order. Normally, the sentence would read *он мог услышать довольно неприятные для себя вещи*, but this would make *вещи* the comment and *неприятные* the topic. Hence, the word order reversal.

Now, what would have happened if the comment would have been *для себя*? It would have gone into the end of the sentence, like this:

> Он мог услышать вещи, довольно неприятные для себя.

*Довольно неприятные для себя* is a normal Russian word order. So as the sentence goes, we have a topic (*вещи*) followed by another topic (*неприятные*), and, hence, we have to intonate the main topic.

Same happens if we are to make *довольно* the comment. We can't just put it to the end of the sentence, but we can replace it with an adverbial clause:

> Он мог услышать вещи, неприятные для себя в достаточной степени.

Same rules apply and we have to separate it with a comma.

---

> Море у его ног лежало безмолвное и белое (Паустовский).

The second example uses a notional copula (*знаменательная связка*). It's a verb which plays both a grammatical role, connecting the subject (*море*) with a predicate (*безмолвное и белое*); and a semantic role, that is can be a predicate on itself (*море лежало* is a valid sentence). The adjectives are predicates here, not the modifiers, hence we don't need a comma.

Compare it to:

> Море было белое и безмолвное.

Comment: +1, но во втором случае определения однородные нераспространенные, а значит, не требующие обособления. У Розенталя тот же пример выглядит иначе, и тут уже Ваше объяснение верно: _Море у его ног лежало безмолвное и белое от облачного неба_.

Comment: Было бы интересно увидеть ответ по сути. Суть вопроса из OP в предложениях `12` и `28`. Последнее — тривиальный случай.

Comment: @Avtokod: The rule is that the extended modifiers following the noun are isolated with a comma, with some exceptions, two of which are explained above. The exceptions don't apply to op's examples, hence, the rule should be applied.

Comment: @jwalker: *он увидел у своих ног море, безмолвное и белое*: comma is definitely required here.

Comment: @Quassnoi So what makes it required? How about _он увидел море безмолвное_? Definitely no comma here. So it must be either _и белое_ or _у своих ног_?

Comment: @Quassnoi I suppose it's the former, but I can't see why adding another adjective makes it require a comma. Also, why don't you apply the same rule here as with _лежало_ from your answer?

Comment: @jwalker: yes, it's the second adjective. Try saying it out loud and you'll see why the comma is required here. Unlike the example with *лежало*, there is no copula in this sentence.

Comment: @Quassnoi Let's try to emphasize the attributes. _Море он увидел безмолвное и белое_ -- does this help?

Comment: @jwalker: help what? You don't need a comma here.

Comment: @Quassnoi Now can the meaning from that last commaless example be applied to _он увидел море безмолвное и белое_? I realize it's not how you'd normally put it, still it seems technically possible to me.

Comment: @jwalker: to omit comma, *море* should be the topic (implied from previous discourse). It's the first rule that applies here in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Со вторым примером всё просто: причастный оборот после определяемого существительного **всегда** выделяется запятыми. Это правило имеет более высокий приоритет, чем другие.

(UPD: не совсем всегда. В соседнем ответе приведено исключение.)

С первым сложнее. Например:

> Он мог услышать вещи для себя довольно неприятные. (М. Ю. Лермонтов)
>
> Он мог услышать вещи, довольно неприятные его жене.

Answer (score -1):

```
 12. Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной, равной пяти сантиметрам.
                                                      └───────────────────────┘
                                                           причастный оборот


 28. Страннее всего происшествия, случающиеся на Невском проспекте!
                                 └────────────────────────────────┘
                                        причастный оборот
```

см. [Обособление причастных оборотов](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85+%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Вашей вины в непонимании нет, поскольку в объяснении к правилам перед упражнением ничего не говорилось о причастных оборотах.

Есть исключение для личных местоимений. Когда запятая должна быть, но разрывает еще одну связь, со сказуемым, то запятая не ставится:

```
      ┌───связь──┐                                                     
  Я сидел погруженный в глубокую задумчивость, как вдруг ...   [Пушкин]
  │      └───────────────────────────────────┘
  │                      |
  └──────связь──────── какой?


                  ┌───связь──┐
  До шалаша мы добежали промокшие насквозь.    [Паустовский]
            │          └──────────────────┘
            │                      |
            └──────связь──────── какие?
```

Comment: "Равной пяти сантиметрам" - не причастный оборот, ибо "равный" - не причастие, а прилагательное.

Comment: @user31264 , да, некоторое время я посомневался тоже. Но затем нашел сл.:"В традиционных русских грамматиках при определении причастий обычно преобладает не представленный выше синтаксический, а семантический подход [Грамматика 1953], [Грамматика 1980]. При таком подходе определения обычно базируются на том утверждении, что причастия сочетают в себе значение процессуальности, характерное для глаголов, и значение признаковости, характерное для прилагательных; иногда при этом говорится, что при помощи причастий действие (процесс) представляется как признак предмета."

Comment: --> [отсюда](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5). Семантически это идентично следующему: "Я прижал к себе коробку стороной, согретой солнцем." Кроме того, нужно быть последовательным, и кроме отрицания сделать утверждение — что это, если не причастный оборот, и почему запятая нужна.

Comment: Непонятно, где в вашей ссылке сказано, или как из того, что вы пишете, следует, что "равный пяти сантиметрам" - причастный оборот.  Согретый - причастие (от согреть).  Равный - не причастие.

Comment: "Кроме того, нужно быть последовательным, и кроме отрицания сделать утверждение — что это, если не причастный оборот, и почему запятая нужна" — этого я не знаю, но любое объяснение должно в том числе объяснять, почему в "вещи для себя довольно неприятные"  запятой нет, а в " вещи, довольно неприятные его жене"  запятая есть.

Comment: @user31264 , чем отличаются `согретая` и `уравненная`? Или `гретая` и `равная`? Насчет возражений, я позволю себе привести пример из математики. Положим, я утверждаю, что пять это число. Мне возражают: нет, это не число, потому что [...]. В математике никто и ухом не поведет на такое "возражение", оно не существует как предмет для рассмотрения, до тех пор, пока возражающий не сделает утверждение — что это, если не число? ))

Comment: "В математике никто и ухом не поведет на такое "возражение", оно не существует как предмет для рассмотрения, до тех пор, пока возражающий не сделает утверждение — что это, если не число?" - неверно, в математике достаточно показать, что не выполнены условия определения.  "Гретая" и "равная" отличаются тем, что первое произошло от глагола "греть", а второе не произошло от глагола.

Comment: @user31264 , не желаете ли утверждать, что глагола [`равнять`](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%F0%E0%E2%ED%FF%F2%FC&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=5&lex2=&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2=) нет?  ))

Comment: Есть!  А вы хотите сказать, что "равный" - причастие от "равнять"? Боюсь, словари с вами не согласны :)

Comment: @avtokod, в словах _согретая_ и _уравненная_ явно присутствует занчение процессуальности, на которые ссылаются «традиционные граматики». В слове _равный_ я лично никакого процесса совершенно не чувствую.

Comment: @Avtokod По-моему, просто же всё. Причастный оборот содержит причастие (я думаю, он поэтому так и называется). Причастие обычно рассматривается, как форма глагола, что, видимо, связано с тем, что у нас в языке они образуются достаточно регулярно. "Равный" — не причастие, а прилагательное; никакой формой глагола это слово не является. Существует глагол «равнять», но связанные с ним причастия, разумеется, — «равняющий» и «равняемый».

Comment: @Shady_arc , `Двум шеренгам дали команду "выравняйся", и они стали выравненными. Затем им дали команду "согрейся", и они стали согретыми. И наконец, им дали команду "равняйся", и они стали равными. ` Равняемый — это из другой оперы. Еще: После процесса "греть" сторона стала гретой. // После процесса "равнять" сторона стала равной. // сторона, нагретая до 5 градусов // сторона, равная 5 см. Проблема у тех, кто полагает омоним причастие/прилагательное считать прилагательным, в том, что им требуется указать правило, по которому ставят запятую. В моем ответе с этим проблем нет.

Comment: @Avtokod У слова _равный_ нет никаких грамматических глагольных свойств, которые должны быть у причастия. А обороты обособляются как с причастием, так и с прилагательным.

Comment: @jwalker :) , **(1)** я согласен, явных глагольных свойств я тоже не обнаружил. Зато нашел, что это известная проблема, и некоторые ученые указывали на семантические признаки. **(2)** Есть омонимы, например, сущ./прил., из математики — `переменная`. Почему бы не быть омониму причастие/прилагательное?  **(3)** обособляемых оборотов всего 7: инфинитивный, субстантивный, адъективный, деепричастный, причастный, спрягаемо-глагольный, и наречный. Каждый из них имеет свою ясную и четкую структуру. К какому типу отнесем обсуждаемый?

Comment: @Avtokod вам просто указали на ошибку. Образование причастий в целом изучается в шестом или седьмом классе. Ничего откровенно сложного там нет. Поэтому и достаточно очевидно, что уж от глагола «равнять» никак нельзя образовать причастие вида «равный». Примерно как от «чистить» не образуется «чистый»: образуются от него только «чистящий», «чистивший», «чистимый», «чищенный» (в лучшем случае). Вопрос об омонимии встаёт только тогда, когда слова действительно одинаковые.

Comment: @Shady_arc А что опровергает Ваш пример `чистый`? `гретый` это причастие? Если не отрицаете, то как его построили из глагола `греть`?

Comment: @Avtokod Я уже запутался, что мы обсуждаем. С тем глаголом всё просто: **греть** → *гре-* → гре- + т → гретый. По тому же правилу от "равнять" образуется "равнянный" (кажется). Собственно, задача решается перебором: страдательные причастия прошедшего времени образуются с помощью суффиксов *-енн*, *-нн* и *-т* (выбор зависит от основы глагола). Ни одного из них в слове "равный" не обнаруживается.

Answer (score -1):

В примере ***"Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной, равной пяти сантиметрам"*** запятой выделяется причастный оборот, а не прилагательное с зависимыми словами. Оно образовано от глагола "равняться", в этом случае ***причастие можно заменить оборотом с глаголом, от которого оно образовано.***

> Начертите равносторонний треугольник со стороной,***которая равняется пяти сантиметрам.***
>   Причастия указывают на признаки, развивающиеся во времени. Здесь именно такой признак.

Comment: a good point on `причастие можно заменить оборотом с глаголом, от которого оно образовано`

Comment: Заменить много что можно, это не характеризующий признак

Comment: @jwalker , щедрое заявление! :) Возьмите и замените: `Я прижал к себе коробку стороной(_) чистой от грязи.` И сделайте, будьте добры, утверждение о необходимости запятой, с кратким указанием оснований.

Comment: @Avtokod Не понимаю, к чему Вы клоните. Что заменить и зачем? Запятая же нужна, т. к. имеется определительный оборот (с прилагательным), стоящий после определяемого существительного.

Comment: @Серж Примеров приводить я не буду, это нас никуда не приведет. Как я уже писал раньше Автокоду, причастие обладает грамматическими категориями глагола, например, временем, которого у прилагательного нет. Рассмотрите предложение _сторона равна пяти_ в прошедшем времени -- увидите, какой там на самом деле глагол.